# How can I use Find to find part of a GameObject name?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NaviMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public ObjectsManipulation om;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float maxFallSpeed = 2f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    public GameObject player;

    private Rigidbody rigid;
    private Waypoints waypoints;
    private Camera navicam;
    private GameObject ground;
    private float distance;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();  //get the rigidbody that attached to the object
    }
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GetComponent<Waypoints>();
        navicam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        ground = GameObject.Find("Floor");
    }
    void FixedUpdate()  //physic should be done in FixedUpdate not Update
    {
        if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && ItemAction.move == true)
        {
            transform.parent = null;  //disconnect the object for it's parent
            om.stopRotation = true;
            rigid.isKinematic = false;
        }
        if (om.stopRotation == true && ItemAction.move == true)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, ground.transform.position);
            if (distance > 1)
            {
                navicam.enabled = true;
                navicam.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
                navicam.transform.forward = transform.forward;
                if (rigid.velocity.sqrMagnitude > maxFallSpeed) //check if it's falling to fast
                {
                    rigid.velocity *= 0.01f; // falling to fast, so reduce speed,  you may want to play around with this number.
                }
                else // if not falling to fast add force to make it fall faster
                {
                    rigid.AddForce(Vector3.down * moveSpeed);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ItemAction.move = false;
                rigid.isKinematic = true;
                waypoints.enabled = true;
                player.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.name.Contains("Floor"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that ground always null:

```
ground = GameObject.Find("Floor");
```

There is no object name Floor but there is an object that it's name part of it contains floor. So it was working fine when I used it inside the OnCollisionEnter I could use Contains.

But now I want to check the distance between the transform that fall down and the ground/floor. Maybe there is a better way to do it maybe using also the OnCollisionEnter ?

The goal is not just making the transform falling down and collid the floor I want the transform to stop falling a bit before the floor like distance 1 or even 3 before colliding with the floor. And I don't want to get each time the object full name since I will use this script in other places.

Comment: You really shouldn't use find-by-name anyway, because it is slow, especially when you have a lot of objects in your scene. There are lots of better ways to find objects. Tags, setting them in the inspector, passing them through singletons or static variables, navigating parent/child relationships of their transforms and more.

Comment: @Philipp Ok so I created a new tag called Floor and then searched for all Floors in the Hierarchy and changed all the Floors to be tagged as Floor. In the script added pritvate GameObject[] ground then in the Start I'm using ground = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Floor");. But now in the script I have many Floors. How do I check the distance from the current Floor I'm on ? I will have to loop over all the Floors in the FixedUpdate and check the distance from each Floor ?

Comment: That would be one option. But if you want to know which floor is below your character, you might want to give the floor a collider and use [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from the character's position to detect the floor below them.